# How to run sql script in SQL Workbench/J from/using command line?

Tags: sql, command-line, sql-workbench-j

I have a small sql query(which uses Wbexport utility) that I need to run daily. I want to automate this task so I am thinking to write a batch file and schedule it using windows task scheduler. Could someone tell me how to run a sql query/.sql file from command line in SQL Workbench/J?

Answer (score 0):

This is documented [in the manual](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/using-scripting.html)

You need to put the query you want to run in a .sql script and then pass the name of the script on the commandline:

```
java -jar sqlworkbench.jar -script=run_export.sql -profile=...
```

or

```
SQLWorkbench64.exe -script=run_export.sql -profile=...
```

There are various ways to define the connection, either through the `-profile` parameter or by specifying the complete [connection information](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/commandline.html#commandline-connect-noprofile). When using the `profile` parameter you need to make sure that the profiles are stored in the default location or specify the location where the profiles are stored.